# Tab bar and tab button

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create Tabs. So using Tab bar and Tab buttons i am creating tabs and using stack layout i am loading the respecting screen.

Note: i dont want to use loader. Using only Stack layout how can i load the screen.
Please suggest how can i do that?

```
Item {
    id:screenTabs

    property var tabname     :  [qsTr("Tab1"),qsTr("Tab2"),qsTr("Tab3"),qsTr("Tab4"),qsTr("Tab5")]
    property var tabScreen   :  ["qrc:/Tabscreen1.qml","qrc:/Tabscreen2.qml","qrc:/Tabscreen3.qml","qrc:/Tabscreen4.qml","qrc:/Tabscreen5.qml"]

    width                    :  parent.width
    height                   :  parent.height

    TabBar
    {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width*0.95
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            topMargin: 15
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: 10
        }

        Repeater
        {
            model: tabname.length
            TabButton
            {
                text: tabname[index]
            }
        }
    }

    StackLayout
    {
        id: stacklyt
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        anchors {
            top: bar.bottom
        }

        Repeater
        {
            model: tabScreen.length
            Loader
            {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                source: tabScreen[index]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also without using loader i am doing below shown way but this is not what i am expecting:

```
StackLayout {
        id: stackLayout
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        anchors.top: bar.bottom

        Item {

        }

        Item {


        }

        Item {

        }

        Item {

        }

        Item {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Loader I think you have to instantiate the component given the name (and not the URI) and put them in a `Container` type (here the `StackLayout`) as you mention in your second solution.

> without using loader i am doing below shown way but this is not what i am expecting

Why is this not what you expect? Did you replace `Item` with your components? You might have to add an `import` statement for your components if you are getting an import error.

```
StackLayout
{
    id: stacklyt
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
    anchors.top: bar.bottom

    Tabscreen1 {}
    Tabscreen2 {}
    Tabscreen3 {}
    Tabscreen4 {}
    Tabscreen5 {}
}
```